# Get only selected data from JPA query

Tags: jpa, repository, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I cound't find any nice solution to get only selected data from the domain?
E.g I have class:

```
@Entity
public class Reservation {

// private Integer RESERVATION_ID;
// private Integer id;
private long code;
private Date date;
private Client reservationClient;
private WashType reservationWashType;
private Vehicle reservationVehicle;
private Wash reservationWash;
private Worker reservationWorkerPesel;
private Review reservationReview;
private ReservationReminder reservationReminder;
 }
```

And have simple query repository

```
public interface ReservationRepository extends JpaRepository<Reservation, Long> {
Reservation findByCode(long code);
}
```

I'd like to take from that query the Reservation object but without data's from class like Review, Worker.
So it means my result should looks like:
**a whole object of Reservation which includes:
code,date,Client reservationClient,WashType reservationWashType,Vehicle reservationVehicle,Wash reservationWash, ReservationReminder reservationReminder**

Is it possible to exclude it in nice way? Or if not how can I manage it?

Comment: Not what you asked for, because you say you actually want Reservation objects, but maybe projections solve your problem even nicer: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily do that so long as `Review` and `Worker` are marked to be lazily loaded.

What I mean is:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Review review;
```

Hibernate won't attempt to load the `Review` association until you call `#getReview()`.

For situations then where you want your `Reservation` with the `Review`, you would then just need to specify at query-time that you want the relationship join-fetched.

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Reservation r JOIN FETCH r.review WHERE r.code = :code")
List<Reservation> findByCode(Long code);
```

Remember, if `Review` cannot be null, make sure that `@ManyToOne` has the `optional=false` attribute so that when the join gets generated, it uses an inner join rather than an outer join to avoid performance overhead.

Comment: Ok, I understand you but I can't get this one:
`@Query("SELECT r FROM Reservation r JOIN FETCH r.review WHERE r.code = :code")`
Why you are joining to the review?
What about If'd like to take all of the sub classes but with lazy loading?

Comment: That is precisely what `JOIN FETCH` does.  It basically is how you, at query time, override the lazy fetch in the mapping model so that Hibernate loads those associations in the base query.  `SELECT r FROM Reservation r JOIN FETCH r.review JOIN FETCH r.worker WHERE r.code = :code`